# Retrieving data from API using Axios Async Await and Typescript. Array length: 1?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, async-await, axios

I have been fighting this for days now and can't seem to find a solution that works.  I just keep going from one error to another.  Currently, I am getting a single entry in my table with no data being populated, just a blank line. Could someone please help me figure out why my table in not populating.

This solution worked perfectly in my sandbox application, but once I put it in the actual project it started failing.  I suspect that is it because the actual project uses Typescript,  and so far Typescript had jacked up almost every enhancement I have tried to add to this app.

**My console.log(res.data) is returning:**

```
[{…}]
   0: {results: (23) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
        totalResultCount: 23
        [[Prototype]]: Object
     length: 1
     lastIndex: (...)
     lastItem: (...)
     [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

As you can see from the console I am getting an array of data with 23 entries, but it is saying a length of 1.  I just can't seem to get it to populate the table with the Array.

My only guess is that the length of 1 is what is causing the single line on the table rather than 23 lines as I would have expected.

**Here is my API call:**

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
      const res = await axios.get(baseURL);
      setTableData([res.data]);
      console.log( res.data );
      console.log( tableData);
      } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      }
      setLoading(false);
 };
 fetchData();
 }, [baseURL, setTableData, setLoading]);
```

**My Table**

```
 {loading ?
   <LoadingData />
   :
   (dataLength === 0 ?
   <NoResults />
  :
  tableData().map((item, id) => (
      <TableRow key={item.index} >
          <TableCell>
              {item.name}
          </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
  )))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in how you render the output

Instead of using ternery operator, you can try this approach:

```
function App() {

const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
      const res = await axios.get(baseURL);

// You can directly use res.data to store API response data in your state
     setData(res.data);
      console.log( res );
      } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      }
      finally {
setLoading(false)
}
 };

React.useEffect(() => {
 fetchData();
 }, [baseURL, setTableData, setLoading]);

return (

// This will appear if data is fetched successfully 
{ tableData && tableData.length > 0 && 
tableData.map((item,index) => (
<TableRow key={index} >
      //... code ...
      </TableRow>
))

)

// This will be shown only if table data array length is 0
{tableData && tableData.length <1 && (<h1>No results </h1>) }

// Show loading text when fetching
{loading && (<h1>Loading</h1>) }
}

export default App;
```

And in a real app, you can replace Loading... text with a circular progress bar from materialui library or an error toast message for errors

Comment: This is a really great way to re-work the code, but once I implement it, I am, starting to get th "e.map is not a function" error and a blank screen.

Comment: What do you mean e.map? It should be tableData.map()... I think I know why that error is, I have edited the solution, I've just removed the brackets around map() function, try the updated solution and let me know if it works